# html page with and iframe inside loaded via ajax is refreshing whole site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html page called store.html with and iframe loading javascript inside (a Nimbit store to be precise), when i call the store.html from the menu via ajax on my index.html the store page is loading normally but when the iframe containing javascript finish loading is refreshing the whole site.
How could I prevent That?
Thanks guys in advance.Easy on my please I am learning...

How I call it Via ajax from index.html menu:

```
<li>
   <a href="store.html" class="page-by-ajax" data-ajax-options='{"target" :"#custom-page"}'>STORE</a>
</li>
```

my frame in store.html

```
<iframe src="http://www.nimbitmusic.com/theit_boy.1"
            marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="ventana_iframe" scrolling="no" border="0" refresh="0"
            frameborder="0" width="800" height="600">
</iframe>
```

Comment: maybe the nimbitmusic.com prevent putting the web in an iframe in other sites, put another url like google.com to check it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough mate. Normally, in ajax load if page gets refreshed.. 1st thing you need to make sure, you "return false" on every call.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see the source of the resultant iFrame page - if it has javascript, it sounds like something in there might be doing a parent.reload